# Issue with TabBar hiding

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

In my application in some view i have a picker at the bottom and tabBar i successfully hidden the tabBar but the problem is the frame allocated  to TabBar is also hiding. so now  the picker is  displayed only half can any one help me out of this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this method it works:

```
[actionSheetPicker showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide tabbar if you hide it will so many create so many problems in this case
instead of hiding use this

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to hide tabbar controller, you just need to add your action sheet in to tabbarcontroller

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont Hide tabbar and try bellow code

```
actionSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
    actionSheet.frame=CGRectMake(0, 100,480 ,232);
    actionSheet.delegate=self;
    picker=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50,480 ,175)];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    [actionSheet addSubview:picker];
    UIToolbar *toolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,480 ,50)];
    toolbar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    NSMutableArray *ButtonArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
    Save=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc ]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(save_pressed)];
    UIBarButtonItem *titleName;
    titleName=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Select Date" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancel=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc ]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel_pressed)];

    [ButtonArray addObject:cancel];
    [cancel release];
    [ButtonArray addObject:space];
    [ButtonArray addObject:titleName];
    [titleName release];
    [ButtonArray addObject:space];
    [space release];
    [ButtonArray addObject:Save];
    [Save release];
    [toolbar setItems:ButtonArray];
    [ButtonArray release];
    [actionSheet addSubview:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];  
    [actionSheet release];
```

Comment: hi why i need action sheet first of all

Comment: i think you are required to picker .in that view u have tabbar then how can add picker to view so i recommended  actionsheet